# PayPal Custom Payment Page with SSL image sources from S3 WITHOUT certificate problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, paypal, certificate

On the PayPal payment page customization you can insert your own URI for the logo and header background.  Obviously it's bad news to insert a non 443 (https) URL, but it also appears that insertion of a secure S3 link is also a major fail.

Initially I inserted my own cname alias to it cdn.mydomain.com and then after seeing an error message from Firefox, thought I needed to pass the actual AWS S3 full path to the bucket which is: `https://cdn.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/paypal/my-logo.png`

Even after doing this, I'm seeing the same problem with Firefox: [image: http://j.mp/vatl8B]

I am figuring that there is a different way to refer to a bucket via a path vs the subdomain for the bucket, but I'm not readily finding the answer.  Or is there an altogether different way to handle this so that there's no certificate issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subdomain/bucketname that doesn't have a dot in it. The cert is only good for `*.s3.amazonaws.com`, not `*.*.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: LOL! Perfect, I have plenty of buckets and I've never simply had a plain name for one (always appended the other domain info as they have always pertained to various sites).  Good call and thanks.